# "Category" vs "Section" in this context

Tags: vocabulary

I have to choose the correct word in the following sentence:

> In the 1730s, Swedish botanist Carl Linnaeus set out rules for
>   classifying species, the most basic biological **category/section**.

According to the key, it is **category**. However, I do not have the slightest notion why **section** doesn't work either.

Here are the Cambridge dictionary definitions:
[category](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/category) [section](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/section)

Comment: Altho' you have linked to the dictionary definitions, you have not indicated which of the various definitions for both *category* & *section* you consider applicable to your sentence.  E.g. which definition of *section* do you consider to be appropriate in the quoted sentence?  Merely providing a dictionary link is not sufficient to overcome the close reason of "lack of research" if you do not explain **why** you consider the definition(s) appropriate / inappriopriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be category because you (Linnaeus) are *categorizing* species. That is, of a large group of disparate elements, you are sorting them into separate, stand-alone *categories* of species.

A *section* is typically understood to be a smaller part of a whole. Take for example a *section* in a book or a *section* in a restaurant. It is a "cut out" (etymology) of a larger piece (like inter*sect*).